# How to Record Audio via Bluetooth device?

Tags: android

how to record Audio from Bluetooth device in Android??? not from device Mic..

when I connect Bluetooth device with Android device then sound recorded via Android device not from Bluetooth device...

Answer (score 1):

manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>
```

code

```
am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, -1);
        Log.d(TAG, "Audio SCO state: " + state);

        if (AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED == state) { 
            /* 
             * Now the connection has been established to the bluetooth device. 
             * Record audio or whatever (on another thread).With AudioRecord you can record with an object created like this:
             * new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
             * AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, audioBufferSize);
             *
             * After finishing, don't forget to unregister this receiver and
             * to stop the bluetooth connection with am.stopBluetoothSco();
             */
            unregisterReceiver(this);
        }

    }
}, new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED));

Log.d(TAG, "starting bluetooth");
am.startBluetoothSco();
```